80s scifi movie in the underworld
I'm trying to find this (80s? or early 90s) movie.  It has a mad scientist dad who builds some sort of machine that discovers an underworld of some sort.  This is like a part of the earth, they can see the people above but the people above can't see them.
He travels there and gets lost, maybe even kidnapped. his daughter then goes to rescue him.  She encounters a series of odd characters, including some "hunky" guy who helps her.  She's maybe in her 20s.
There is some really fat guy with huge eyelashes, like the head of some group/gang.
This seemed to be an American film.  A campy type movie, low rating 
Thanks if you have any idea!

Where was it set? Was it an American film? What happens when his daughter goes to rescue him? Can you remember what any of the cast looked like? Any little detail you can remember might help someone to find the movie for you!

Alien from L.A. has a scientist finding a hidden world underground, lots of weird characters and a macho hero helping the heroine, who is the scientist's daughter.

The film was featured on Mystery Science Theater 3000. Ah ha!

Ah you totally got it, and solved this mystery, thank you!
